# Why am I getting this error when converting m4a file? “Unknown encoder 'libfdk_aac'”

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

I am on Windows and am using the latest March 20, 2021 version of FFmpeg: `ffmpeg-4.3.2-2021-02-27-essentials_build.zip`

When I use this command to try and convert audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4a -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he_v2 -b:a 32k output.m4a
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown encoder 'libfdk_aac'
```

How to solve it?

I have no idea how to add/install `libfdk_aac` to FFmpeg, so I need a proper guide and solution.

Comment: Windows or Linux?  Similar question>>>>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774975/unknown-encoder-libfaac

Comment: What OS are you using and what version of FFmpeg are you using? Are you sure you want to use `aac_he_v2` or are you just following some instructions you found online? `aac_he_v2` is the High Efficiency AAC (HE-AAC) codec and if FFmpeg wasn't compiled with it, it won’t be there.

Comment: It's Windows and Ffmpeg version is leatest march 20, 2021

''ffmpeg-4.3.2-2021-02-27-essentials_build.zip''

Answer (score 3):

The libfdk license is not compatible with the GNU General Public License. It cannot be distributed with GPL licensed `ffmpeg`.

What you can do:

- [Compile `ffmpeg` by yourself](https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers) and enable support for libfdk, or
- Use a different AAC encoder such as the [built-in FFmpeg AAC encoder](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC), or
- Use an external, standalone HE-AAC encoder such as [fdkaac](https://github.com/nu774/fdkaac).